# Is "the way how" grammatically incorrect?

Tags: grammaticality, speech

(I am not a native speaker so my writing probably seems to be odd. Please understand some Non-grammar...)

I learned that "the way how" is grammatically wrong because  'the way' and 'how' have same meaning so it can stir up confusion or reduplication. And I can understand that explanation. BUT I think that if "the way how" is wrong, "the reason why" and "the time when" etc should be wrong, too. But I've NEVER heard and learned they are wrong too.

I am really really confused...  I can't understand why ONLY "the way how" is grammatically incorrect (or not). PLEASE help me... ( If you think that "the way how" isn't grammatically wrong and just unnatural expression, please give me reliable phrase... I'm not a native speaker so I can't realize what is unnatural spoken expression. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re right that *the way how* is not acceptable. The reason is that *how* is not normally used as a relative word so we can’t say * *This is the way how we do it*.  We can, though, say *This is* [*how we do it*], but the bracketed element is not a relative clause but a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) with the meaning "*This is the answer to the question* '*how do we do it*?'" Note though that we can say *This is the way* [*that* *we do it*], where the bracketed relative clause modifies *way*.

But *why* is different. *The reason* [*why* *Ed got angry*] is fine. *Why* is a relative word here that introduces the bracketed relative clause modifying  *reason*.

And *when* is also a relative word in, for example, *I remember the time* [*when* *you could buy a house for less than £3,000*], where it introduces the bracketed relative clause.